# Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout keyboard problem

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a strange UI glitch for the keyboard when the ModalBottomSheetLayout is in expanded state and the keyboard appears.

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {
    val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, skipHalfExpanded = true)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = state,
        sheetContent = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
                repeat(20) {
                    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        Button(onClick = { scope.launch { state.show() } }) {
            Text("Click to show sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IMU4kGY3hnixK6bVME1iqH0aPDe4-hjr/view?usp=sharing

Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
windowSoftInputMode adjustResize
```

to your `fragment` / `activity`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a bug on the Compose library. Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230652481

Try updating to Compose 1.4.0